# Showing the history of commits in the shape of a tree

Tags: git

I am trying to show the history of commits in my git branches in a shape of a tree using the following command:

```
git log --oneline --graph --all
```

but what I receive is incomplete. One of the branches (Serendipity) is not shown as a separate branch.

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

> EDIT

I switched to each branch and got a log of all commits:

```
Master
```

[image]

```
Serendipity
```

[image]

```
Sidebranch
```

[image]

As you can see there are changes exclusive to each branch, so I expect to see those in a separate branch when I use `git log --graph --all`

Comment: Why would it be separate? It appears to share its entire history with `master` and just add two commits on top.

Comment: The thing is I have three branches (master, sidebranch, and serendipity) and I made different changes in each branch. But here I can only see two separate branches. Seems master and serendipity are somehow merged!

Comment: They're not "somehow merged", they're just almost entirely the same. If you added another commit on `master` that wasn't in `serendipity` you'd see the branch, but at the moment there's nothing to show "next to" `serendipity`'s commits like there is with `sidebranch`'s. To put it another way: `69224a7` only has one child commit (whereas `a3dc99a` has two); making a new commit on `master` would give it a second.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you check my edit?

Comment: That hasn't added any information, that's the same thing that was shown in the `--all` view to begin with (which is the point of it). In particular note that the log for `serendipity` shows you that it is `master` plus two additional commits. There is no issue here to fix, it's showing you the right information. Also, in general, please don't post screenshots of text content - it's not indexable or accessible.

Comment: Yesss, got it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From graph we can see following history:

1. a3dc99a - last pushed `master`
2. 7b66735 - branched out `sidebranch` with 2 commits
3. 69224a7 - current state of `local master` (probably not pushed)
4. 32f78f1 - branched out `serendipity` branch from local master with 2 commits on top of this branch

So `serendipity` is for sure a separate branch which just shares the same history with master up to 69224a7.

UPDATE: In response to your edit I combined your screenshots and added red line to show that below line the history is the same:
[image]

You can see clearly here that `serendipity` and `master` share the same history and `serendipity` has additional 2 new commits.